# Magento : Get product image by label, even if excluded

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I would like to get a product image and display it on the product view page, based on two criteria:

- by specific label
- by status (i.e. excluded = yes)

This post contains the solution for the first criteria (by label), however I can't figure out how to extend on that solution to display said image even if it is "excluded".

Here is the code used for step 1 :

```
$prodimg = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label','prodimg');
if ($prodimg != '') {
    echo "<img src='" .$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $prodimg->getFile()). "' class='img-responsive' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

magento media attribute a have field name disabled or exclude which tell which image are in excluded list

check:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image):
/* product image in exclude in list */
if( $_image->getExclude()==1){
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail',     
$_image->getFile())->resize(301);
}
endforeach;
```

For getting non exclude try getDisabled()==0 because it save it on database as 0

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image):

    if( $_image->getDisabled()==0){
    $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(301);
    }
    endforeach;
```